# Android: How to build WebView to enable WebRTC/H264 - Chrome Works

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264

I saw an answer to the question of how to enable WebRTC/H264 in WebView is you need to build your own WebView with ffmpeg (h264) flags turned on.  Is this statement true? I am able to display the webrtc/h264 video in Chrome on my Android so I know my hardware (phone) is wWebRTC/H264 capable.  My question is a follow up how do I build my own Chromium WebView with ffmpeg (h264) enabled?  What are the flags??

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md) by adding the modifications reported in [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719023#c36) comment... Maybe someone can also try it, in order to understand together...